# laravel 7.15 Undefined offset: 38 Maatwebsite Excel import and export

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using Maatwebsite excel to import and export xlsx file. I have used this before with other app and it's working. In my second app I'm getting an error.

> Undefined offset: 3

I don't understand, what I'm doing wrong.Everything is same as my other app.

Here's my controller:

```
$products = Excel::toArray(new ProductsImport(), $request->file('file'));

    //  dd($products);

    foreach($products[0] as $row) {
        
        $arr[] = [
            'coil_id' => $row[1],
            'category' => $row[2],
            'product_family' => $row[3],
        ];
    }

if(!empty($arr)){
        DB::table('products')->insert($arr);
    }
      
    return back()->with('toast_success', 'Excel file uploaded to database successfully');
```

Even export isn't working too. It just takes me to a blank page localhost/products/export

Comment: you will need to check the returned data ... seems for at least one of these rows index 3 doesn't exist, based on that error (assuming it relates to the code shown)

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. All rows exist in data-table.

Comment: if that error has to do with the code you are showing then some `$row` does not have an index '3' ... when you get to that loop some `$row` does not have a index `3` in it

Comment: Ok. So how should I index row? Should I start from "0"?

Comment: you need to look at the data you have and decide based on how it is coming through, but usually indexes start at `0`

Comment: Ok I'll change the indexes and can you tell me why export wouldn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216380/discussion-between-nargesh-rana-and-lagbox).